# Check view postion towards other view using UI Automator

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Basically the question.
I have created a tile for a WearOS, with two elements, and i want to check their positions towards each other in simple test - view X should be on the left of Y, and Y should be to the right of X respectively.
Views are selected by using `UiSelector.resourceIdMatches(...)`, without using Espresso framework

So far i tried to compare center bounds of a view, by getting it using someview.perform.bounds.centerX, by i thinks it's not validate anything closely related to view positioning.

Is this possible at all, or it's a dead end ?